# How to use a React Project for an entire subroute of html website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have an existing HTML page and a React project. How to connect them?

home.html

```html
<button>go to React page</button>
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/mypage" element={<Mypage />}>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I want to click the "go to React page" button, and I can navigate to `"/mypage"`?

Answer (score 1):

The button should effect a navigation action to `"/mypage"` URL that ideally is serving your React app.

**home.html**

Update the button to include a click handler that redirects to the sub-route

```html
<button onclick="navigateToReactApp()">go to React page</button>
```

```js
const navigateToReactApp = () => {
  window.location.href = "/mypage"; // check the path correctness
};
```

or use an anchor tag which is likely semantically more correct.

```html
<a href="/mypage">go to React page</a>
```

**App.js**

Update the router to make all routes/links/etc work *relative* from the `"/mypage"` where the app is hosted/served from by setting the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/mypage">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Mypage />}>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```